# SSIS restart/ re-trigger package automatically

Tags: ssis

Good day!
I have a SSIS package that retrieves data from a database and exports it to a flat file (simple process). The issue I am having is that the data my package retrieves each morning depends on a separate process to load the data into a table prior to my package retrieving it.

Now, the process which initially loads the data does inserts metadata into a table which shows the start and end date/time. I would like to setup something in my package that checks the metadata table for an end date/time for the current date. If the current date exists, then the process continues... IF no date/ time exists then the process stops (here is the kicker) BUT the package re-triggers itself automatically an hour later to check if the initial data load is complete.

I have done research on checkpoints, etc. but all that seems to cover is if the package fails it would pick up where it left when the package is restarted. I don't want to manually re-trigger the process, I'd like it to check the metadata and re-start itself if possible. I could even put in processing that if it checks the metadata 3 times it would stop completely.

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: If I understand, the package would essentially check to see if the data is loaded into the source table with a current date timestamp, and then export this data to a flat file if it does?  And if there are no rows from the current date in the source table then the package would just not execute and repeat this again in one hour?

Comment: How does the process initially get launched? SQL Agent, some other scheduling tool?

Answer (score 1):

What you want isn't possible exactly the way you describe it.  When a package finishes running, it's inert.  It can't re-trigger itself, something has to re-trigger it.

That doesn't mean you have to do it manually.  The way I would handle this is to have an agent job scheduled to run every hour for X number of hours a day.  The job would call the package every time, and the meta data would tell the package whether it needs to do anything or just do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There would be a couple of ways to handle this.

They all start by setting up the initial check, just as you've outlined above. See if the data you need exists. Based on that, set a boolean variable (I'll call it `DataExists`) to `TRUE` if your data is there or `FALSE` if it isn't. Or `1` or `0`, or what have you.

Create two `Precedent Contraints` coming off that task; one that requires that `DataExists==TRUE` and, obviously enough, another that requires that `DataExists==FALSE`.

The `TRUE` path is your happy path. The package executes your code.

On the `FALSE` path, you have options.

Personally, I'd have the `FALSE` path lead to a forced failure of the package. From there, I'd set up the job scheduler to wait an hour, then try again. BUT I'd also set a limit on the retries. After X retries, go ahead and actually raise an error. That way, you'll get a heads up if your data never actually lands in your table.

If you don't want to (or can't) get that level of assistance from your scheduler, you could mimic the functionality in SSIS, but it's not without risk.

On your `FALSE` path, trigger an `Execute SQL Task` with a simple [`WAITFOR DELAY '01:00:00.00'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) command in it, then have that task call the initial check again when it's done waiting. This will consume a thread on your SQL Server and *could* end up getting dropped by the SQL Engine if it gets thread starved.

Going the second route, I'd set up another `Iteration` variable, increment it with each try, and set a limit in the precedent constraint to, again, raise an actual error if you're data doesn't show up within a reasonable number of attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your help! With some additional research I found the following article that I was able to reference and create a solution for my needs. Although my process doesn't require a failure to attempt a re-try, I set the process to force fail after 3 attempts.

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2014/06/retry-task-on-failure.html

Much appreciated
Best wishes